# Opencart 'Product Options' Overloaded

Tags: opencart

I am using opencart and previous developer used lots option values for color. It is more than 80,000. Now when I am trying to add new options to product it doesn't load the options. I want to simplify and narrow down the 80,000 + options values to 300 and add Size option but no product take that and if I delete the color option  i have to edit thousands of products which i don't wanna do. is there any way where it is possible to solve this issue in short time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to solve parts of that issue on the database layer first. You could start adding indexes so your options will load again in the UI. Then you also might be able to add other options again.

For replacing 80000+ options with 300 you might want to consider writing a PHP script that will first store the old ID's, then insert the new 300 options, then replace the references to the old IDs with references to the new IDs, finally (if all went well) delete the old options.